# Spark 2.0, DataFrame, filter a string column, unequal operator (!==) is deprecated

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to filter a DataFrame by keeping only those rows that have a certain string column non-empty.

The operation is the following:

```
df.filter($"stringColumn" !== "")
```

My compiler shows that the !== is deprecated since I moved to Spark 2.0.1

How can I check if a string column value is empty in Spark > 2.0?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use `=!=` as a replacement:

```
df.filter($"stringColumn" =!= "")
```

Comment: thanks LostInOverflow, can you point me where you find the information in Spark documentation?

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.Column, check   deprecation comment for `!==`.

Comment: @Rami It is full answer, according to StackOverflow rules you should accept it

Comment: This seems deprecated in Spark 2. I get extraneous input '!='

Answer (score 2):

Use `=!=` as "not equal" operator

```
df.where(col("COLUMN_NAME") =!= "")
```