# Why I'm getting type mismatch when filtering rows for a specific aggregate with spark sql?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, parquet

So I have this dataframe `sheepDF`:

```
--------------------------------------
| sheep_id | sheep_age | sheep_color |
--------------------------------------
|    1     |     1     |    gray     |
|    2     |     2     |    grey     |
|    3     |     2     |             |
|    4     |     3     |    white    |
|    5     |     3     |             |
--------------------------------------
```

I want to group by `sheep_age`, but exclude the empty string from aggregate. So the result should be like this:

```
--------------------------------------
| sheep_id | sheep_age | sheep_color |
--------------------------------------
|    1     |     1     |    gray     |
|   2,3    |     2     |    grey     |
|   4,5    |     3     |    white    |
--------------------------------------
```

instead of this:

```
--------------------------------------
| sheep_id | sheep_age | sheep_color |
--------------------------------------
|    1     |     1     |    gray     |
|   2,3    |     2     |   grey,     |
|   4,5    |     3     |   white,    |
--------------------------------------
```

I tried following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43739158/9183891) to solve my problem.

Here is my code:

```
def get: DataFrame = {
  sheepDF
    .select(
      $"sheep_id".as("sheep_id"),
      $"sheep_age".as("sheep_age"),
      $"sheep_color".as("sheep_color")
    )
    .groupBy(
      $"sheep_age"
    )
    .agg(
      concat_ws(",",
        collect_list(
          $"sheep_id"
        ))
        .as("sheep_ids"),
      concat_ws(",",
        collect_list(
          when($"sheep_color" != "", $"sheep_color")
        ))
        .as("sheep_colors")
    )
}
```

But, I got this error:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Boolean
[error]  required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
[error]             when($"sheep_color" != "",
[error]                                      ^
```

Why it tells me `required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column`? What am I missing? `When` function should need `Boolean` right?

Comment: What you want is a column with booleans. Try to use `=!=` instead. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154104/spark-2-0-dataframe-filter-a-string-column-unequal-operator-is-deprecat

Comment: @PikoMonde you can use function like this "collect_list(when(col("sheep_color").isNotNull, $"sheep_color") ))" let me know if you again face any issue

Comment: @Shaido thx, it works! Please create it as answer so I can accept it. @maheshgupta, it didn't work for `isNotNull`, because the content is actually an empty string, not null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want here is a column of booleans while `!=` returns a boolean and not a column. Spark defines two equality operators for columns: equal to `===` and not equal to `=!=`. Both these returns a column of booleans which are the result of the comparisons of the elements of the two columns being compared.

In short, change `$"sheep_color" != ""` to `$"sheep_color" =!= ""` to solve the error.

---

Some more insights of why `===` is used instead of `==` can be found here: [Difference between == and === in Scala, Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490236/difference-between-and-in-scala-spark)